# visual studio 2010 / resharper 6 code layout

Tags: asp.net, formatting, resharper

Does anyone know if there's a way in either the 2010 IDE directly or using something like Resharper to have it reformat the asp.net code in the following way.

If I've got a control written like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress1" runat="server" CssClass="somethingHere" />
```

it won't do anything to it. However, if I've got something longer like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ValidationGroup="grpSample" Display="None" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtfirstName" ErrorMessage="Missing!"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

it will format it like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ValidationGroup="grpSample" 
    Display="None" 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1"                                        
    runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="txtfirstName" 
    ErrorMessage="Missing!"
>
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

With each property on a new line? So if a control reaches a certain length it reformats as above?

I've searched for quite a while and can't see a way of doing this, but in the case of controls like repeaters, gridviews etc. i find the second layout a lot easier to read.

Comment: Unfortunately we still haven't implemented a full HTML/ASP.NET code formatter. We only indent code in HTML/ASP.NET now. The full formatter is in plans, but I cannot promise that it would be in the next ReSharper version.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, presumably if it's not possible through resharper then I imagine I'm right in guessing that it's not possible through Visual Studio directly?

Comment: Did you try changing Tools | Options -> Text Editor | HTML | Formatting -> Wrap tags when exceeding specified length ? If it doesn't do what you want then I guess it's not possible via VS.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that just wraps the tags but doesn't arrange them nicely as per the example. I look forward to seeing what Resharper come up with for this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this isn't possible. Would've been nice....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does provide an answer, the answer is that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

if you work with c# or VB.net you will find in Menu Resharper => option => Code Editing => c#=> Line Breaks and Wrapping => Right margin (colmns) this will be the number of column in your pages, change it to the the lenght you want.

if you work with VB :  Code Editing => VB.Net =>

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't affect the asp.net code and it doesn't allow for the scenario outlined above. If I lower the right margin all it does is move the code to the next line to fit. Unfortunately it doesn't allow for putting each asp.net control property on it's own line.